# Dados de uma Array (Angular)

Tags: array, angular, typescript, binding

Estou tentando utilizar os dados de uma Array para colocar em um objeto.. por ex:

```
lembreteSistemaList = LembreteSistema [] = [];
lembreteSistema = LembreteSistema = new LembreteSistema();

recuperarLembrete () {
...
.subscribe((lembreteSistemaVar: Array <LembreteSistema> ) => {
this.lembreteSistemaList = lembreteSistemaVar
}
```

quero pegar este **lembreteSistemaList** e colocar dentro do **lembreteSistema** para que no html possa usar assim

```
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"> {{ lembreteSistema.nome }} </textarea>
```

obs: ja tentei utilizar o *ngFor no html mas nao deu certo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara é porque esse lembreteSistemaList é um array de objetos nesse caso você poderia fazer algo desse tipo.

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" *ngFor="let lembrete of lembreteSistemaList"> {{ lembrete.nome }} </textarea>
```

Porque ai sim você estará acessando o objeto dentro do array ou poderia fazer usando o pipe json 'vai ficar muito feio porém resolveria seu caso'

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"> {{ lembreteSistemaList | json }} </textarea>
```

Ou para deixar mais fácil ainda usaria assim

```
lembreteSistemaList$: Observable<LembreteSistema[]>;

    <ng-container *ngIf="lembreteSistemaList$ | async as lembreteSistemaList">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" *ngFor="let lembrete of lembreteSistemaList"> {{ lembrete.nome }} </textarea>
    </ng-container>
```